# What is the Docker Engine?

Tags: docker

When people talk about the 'Docker Engine' do they mean both the Client and the Daemon? Or is it something else entirely?

As I see it there is a Docker Client, a Docker Daemon. The Client runs locally and connects to the Daemon which does the actual running of the containers. The Client can connect to a remote Daemon. Are these both together the Engine? thanks

Comment: Did you google "Docker Engine"? The very first result is the [Docker Engine](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-engine) page

Comment: yes. it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

The Docker Engine is the Docker Daemon running on a single host, installed with the Docker Client CLI. [Here are the docs that answer this specific question](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/).

On top of that, you can have a Swarm running that joins multiple hosts to horizontally scale and provide fault tolerance. And there are numerous other projects from Docker, like their Registry, Docker Cloud, and Universal Control Plane, that are each separate from the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Docker engine is a client-server application which comprises of 3 components.
1. Client: Docker CLI or the command line window that helps us to interact.
2. REST API: Client communicate with the server with REST API, the commands issued by the client is sent to the server in the form of REST API, it is this reason our server can either be in the local or remote machine.
3. Server: Server here is either the local or remote machine or host machine which has a daemon process running in it which receives the commands and creates, manages and destroys the docker objects like images, containers, volumes etc.